Resolving Frame-Metadata Version Conflict Between Dependencies while updating version of substrate project
There seems to be a frame-metadata crate error where 2 versions are being referenced which is causing the error. The 2 versions are v16.0.0 and v18.0.0. The issue is that the substrate-wasm-builder and the merkleized-metadata crates are using frame-metadata v18.0.0 as a dependency where as the rest of the crates that uses frame-metadata as a dependency are using v16.0.0. I ried forcing the versions to comply with v16.0.0 using several methods including modifying the Cargo.toml root file, referencing github repositories as dependencies, etc with no luck.

